# Проблема с доступом к приватным полям базового класса

Tags: python, ооп

Код:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__field = 13 # private field for inner uses only

class Child(Parent):
    """docstring for Child"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()

    def ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField(self):
        return self.__field

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Child()
    c.ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField()
```

Вывод интерпретатора:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 20, in <module>
    c.ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField()
  File "foo.py", line 16, in ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField
    return self.__field
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '_Child__field'
```

Я, конечно, могу использовать `property` для этих целей, но всё-таки хотелось бы обращаться к родительским атрибутам напрямую и не писать при этом `self._Parent__field`.

Comment: Не знаю синтаксиса питона, но по словам

> хотелось бы обращаться к родительским атрибутам

Это private поля и наследование?

Comment: @Montreal, зачем вам прописывать родительским свойствам приватность, если вы хотите обращаться к ним из дочернего класса?

Comment: @Etki потому что это свойство должно быть у двух дочерних классов, и никто из других классов не должен знать об этом свойстве. 

Я задал этот же вопрос на StackOverflow и, судя по ответам и комментариям, необходимо либо использовать одиночное подчёркивание и или писать @property без сеттера.

Comment: @Montreal, сейчас, наверное, нет языка, в котором при желании нельзя достать приватное свойство, в питоне это вообще пустая формальность из-за Name Mangling. Смысл приватных и защищенных свойств не в невозможности к ним достучаться, а в освобождении публичного интерфейса от ненужного хлама и правильной архитектуре. Protected-свойств в питоне нет вообще, но в принципе, думаю, можно намудрить проверку обращающегося класса.

Answer (score 2):

Когда идешь в универ, говорят "забудь все, чему учили в в школе". Когда идешь работать, говорят "забудь все, чему тебя учили в универе". К чему это я.

Когда начинаешь программировать на Python, забудь Java и C++. Когда меняешь парадигмы (статическая vs динамическая типизация ), нужно менять способ мышления. Приватные переменные, шаблоны, дженерики, паттерны проектирования, приватные и защищенные переменные, создание классов на каждый чих - все это не про Python.

Делать приватную переменную, и навешивать на него свойство это неправильно в принципе. Геттеры и сеттеры, которые не скрывают никакой реализации это свидетельство плохого дизайна.

А как же правильно?

Сделайте переменную с нижнего подчеркивания, всем будет понятно что это не публичный интерфейс, и лучше ее не трогать. А если тронут, и не покроют это место тестами - сами себе Буратины. И не надо быть готовым, что приватную переменную кто нибудь поменяет, это все должно быть на совести того, кто пользуется этим классом. Создавая такую переменную вы тем самым создаете контракт. Нарушая этот контракт странно ожидать от класса корректного поведения.

Comment: От души спасибо за добрый совет (не сарказм)

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно обращаетесь с приватными полями.
Примерно так:

```
self.__a=0 # свойство

@property
def a(self):
    return self.__a

@a.setter
def a(self, val=None):
    self.__a=val

@a.deleter
def a(self):
    del(self.__a)
```

Comment: Да я знаю про **property**. Просто я хотел переменные скрыть в базовом классе, чтобы ими могли пользоваться только классы-потомки. В С++ или Java это, вроде, называется **protected**, а не **private**. Вообще мне это начало надоедать, и я стал использовать _var вместо __var.

Comment: @Montreal, питон не C++ и не Java. В питоне все эти приватные поля - просто пометка для программиста и не более. И с одной стороны, в питоне стоит проще относиться к канонам ООП, с другой стороны надо быть готовым, что "приватную" переменную кто-нибудь может все-таки поменять.